# How do I send an object to a GET endpoint that takes in a Java object (Angular)?

Tags: java, angular, http, get

There is an object like this (more than one field, but just one for this ex)

```java
public class MyObject{
  private String objString;

  public String getObjString(){
   return objString;
  }

 public void setObjString(String str){
  this.objString = str;
 }
}
```

and a wrapper for it to take multiple

```java
public class MyObjects{
 private List<MyObject> objects;
 ... getters and setters for list...
}
```

and an endpoint like this

```java
@GetMapping("/sample")
public ResponseEntity<String> sampleEndpoint(MyObjects objs){...}
```

What should I be doing to send it properly?  I have tried making a mock model of it and sending it over as a request param but that is not working.  I am able to hit the endpoint in the browser if I do a url like

'/sample?objs%5B0%5D.objString=test&objs%5B1%5D.objString=test1'

but am not sure what the best method to do this in angular is.

Comment: Obviously a post is better. But did you try to do a JSON.stringify on the object?

Comment: does it make sense to post if the goal is to get data back?  I have not tried it, I will try.

Comment: GET requests *can* have a body, but that's very unconventional. A POST request is intended to create data, PUT/PATCH is to update, etc. A way you can send the object through the querystring is convert it to base64 first, but the endpoint would have to decode it.